# Select users from date timestamp - only return the last week

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a subset of users who joined a site within the last week

The table is `users` and date field (`dateadded`) is unix timestamp e.g. `2012-04-29 17:31:57`

Here's what I'm trying but its returning all users:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE dateadded <= NOW() AND dateadded >= DATE_SUB(dateadded, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: I dont think `2012-04-29 17:31:57` is a **unix timestamp**. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong condition.  You want `now()` for both comparisons:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE dateadded <= NOW() AND dateadded >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was close but no cigar!